How to use PyHamcrest with nested dictionaries and lists
I'm trying to use PyHamcrest python library to validate if a nested dictionary (sub graph) is a subset of a another larger nested dictionary (full graph).
In the example below, I'm trying to validate if the subset of nodes (and their sublist of properties) of the subgraph json found in the list of all nodes (and their list of all properties) in the full graph json.
Sample data below for reference:
a subgraph json is
{
    "nodes": [{
        "properties": [{
            "key": "key11",
            "value": ["val11", "val12"]
        }, {
            "key": "key12",
            "value": "val21"
        }],
        "types": ["t11", "t12"]
    }]
}

a full graph json is (simplified)
{
    "graph": {
        "id": "graph_id",
        "timestamp": "str_of_time",
        "nodes": [{
                "id": "node_id1",
                "properties": [{
                    "key": "key11",
                    "value": ["val11", "val12"]
                }, {
                    "key": "key12",
                    "value": "val21"
                }, {
                    "key": "key13",
                    "value": "val31"
                } {
                    "key": "key14",
                    "value": ["val41", "val42"]
                }],
                "types": ["t11", "t12", "t13", "t14"]
            },
            {
                "id": "node_id2",
                "properties": [{
                    "key": "key21",
                    "value": ["val21", "val22"]
                }, {
                    "key": "key22",
                    "value": "val23"
                }],
                "types": ["t21", "t22"]
            },
            ...and a lot of other nodes....
        ],
        "edges": [{
                "id": "edge_id1",
                "properties": [],
                "type": "type1",
                "source": {
                    "id": "source_id1",
                    "resolutionType": "source_res1"
                },
                "target": {
                    "id": "target_id1",
                    "resolutionType": "target_res1"
                }
            }, {
                "id": "edge_id2",
                "properties": [{
                    "key": "key1",
                    "value": "val1"
                }, {
                    "key": "key2",
                    "value": "val2"
                }],
                "type": "type2",
                "source": {
                    "id": "source_id2",
                    "resolutionType": "source_res2"
                },
                "target": {
                    "id": "target_id2",
                    "resolutionType": "target_res2"
                }
            }
            ...and a lot of other edges....
        ]
    }
}

This is what I tried but then it fails because it's expecting a FULL list of dictionaries and not just the sub dictionary.
    assert_that(
      full_graph["graph"]["nodes"],
      has_items(sub_graph["nodes"])
    )

I get error
AssertionError: 
Expected: (a sequence containing <[list of ALL nodes in sub graph]>)
     but: a sequence containing <[list of ALL nodes of full graph]>. # how do I set this to only list of expected nodes and NOT ALL nodes in full graph?

Additional info on the structure (if it's not coming out of the example json above)

graph - dict

id - str
timestamp - str
nodes - list of dicts
edges - list of dicts
each node

id -> str
types -> list of str
properties -> list of dicts


each edge

id -> str
type -> str
properties -> list of dicts
source -> dict
target -> dict





So, I'm probably using the library in a wrong way and not able to figure out how to check that a subgraph json is a subset of the full graph json.
Regards,
Rumit

There's no built-in matcher which does what you want. You're going to need to write a custom matcher for this.
